# Erro ao desserializar um Json que recebo do servidor

Tags: c#, json

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Gnaritas.Coletor.Modelos.CampoFormularioColecao' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like `List<T>` that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
> Path '', line 1, position 1.

Estou desenvolvendo em C#

Minha classe que realiza desserialização:

```
public List<Coleta> SolicitarResumo()
    {
        List<CampoFormulario> dados = new List<CampoFormulario>();

        dados.Add(new CampoFormulario(TokenService.ObterCodUser(), "usuar-sep") { dataType = "character", type = "input" });
        //dados.Add(new CampoFormulario(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(), "data-sep") { type = "input", dataType = "datetime" });

        CampoFormularioColecao campoColecao = new CampoFormularioColecao("valor");
        campoColecao.type = "output";
        campoColecao.value.fields.Add(new Field("cdd-embarq", "Codigo") { type = "integer" });
        campoColecao.value.fields.Add(new Field("nome-abrev", "Cliente"));
        campoColecao.value.fields.Add(new Field("vl-cliente", "Valor") { type = "decimal" });

        dados.Add(campoColecao);

        string dadosJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dados);

        callProcedureWithToken chamada = new callProcedureWithToken()
        {
            arg0 = TokenService.ObterToken(),
            arg1 = "esp/esae0000.p",
            arg2 = "pi-retorna-usuar-valor",
            arg3 = dadosJson
        };

        callProcedureWithTokenResponse resposta = cliente.callProcedureWithToken(chamada);

        CampoFormularioColecao registrosDicionario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CampoFormularioColecao>(resposta.@return);
```

Tipo de dados para o qual desejo deserializar o json:

```
 public class CampoFormularioColecao : CampoFormulario
{
    public CampoFormularioColecao(string tipo)
    {
        dataType = "temptable";
        name = "tt-lista-" + tipo;
        value = new Value() { name = this.name };
    }

    public new Value value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public Value()
    {
        fields = new List<Field>();
        records = new List<JObject>();
    }

    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }

    public List<JObject> records { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public Field(string pname, string plabel)
    {
        label = plabel;
        name = pname;
        type = "character";
    }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Este é o Json que recebo:

```
[{
"dataType": "temptable",
"name": "tt-lista-valor",
"value": "{\"records\":[{\"vl-cliente\":240.12,\"cdd-embarq\":341647,\"nome-abrev\":\"MULT CHAVES\"},{\"vl-cliente\":1906.0,\"cdd-embarq\":341647,\"nome-abrev\":\"MULT CHAVES\"},{\"vl-cliente\":240.12,\"cdd-embarq\":341647,\"nome-abrev\":\"MULT CHAVES\"},{\"vl-cliente\":345.78,\"cdd-embarq\":341647,\"nome-abrev\":\"MULT CHAVES\"}],\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"cdd-embarq\",\"label\":\"Codigo\",\"type\":\"integer\"},{\"name\":\"nome-abrev\",\"label\":\"Cliente\",\"type\":\"character\"},{\"name\":\"vl-cliente\",\"label\":\"Valor\",\"type\":\"decimal\"}]}",
"type": "output"
```

}]

Parece que não reconhece o tipo CampoFormularioColecao ... Bem, como eu disse, sou novo aqui, peço desculpas se não fui suficientemente claro ou se eu pedisse algo trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Json postado acima está com problemas de formação. Abaixo você pode encontrar um exemplo de código que deserializa o Json formatado de forma correta.

As classes de modelo:

```
public class MinhaClasse
{
    public string dataType { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Value value { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public List<Record> records { get; set; }
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    [JsonProperty("vl-cliente")]
    public string vlcliente { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("cdd-embarq")]
    public string cddembarq { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("nome-abrev")]
    public string nomeabrev { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

E a deserialização do Json:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"[{""dataType"":""temptable"",""name"":""tt-lista-valor"",""value"":{""records"":[{""vl-cliente"":240.12,""cdd-embarq"":341647,""nome-abrev"":""MULT CHAVES""},{""vl-cliente"":1906.0,""cdd-embarq"":341647,""nome-abrev"":""MULT CHAVES""},{""vl-cliente"":240.12,""cdd-embarq"":341647,""nome-abrev"":""MULT CHAVES""},{""vl-cliente"":345.78,""cdd-embarq"":341647,""nome-abrev"":""MULT CHAVES""}],""fields"":[{""name"":""cdd-embarq"",""label"":""Codigo"",""type"":""integer""},{""name"":""nome-abrev"",""label"":""Cliente"",""type"":""character""},{""name"":""vl-cliente"",""label"":""Valor"",""type"":""decimal""}]},""type"":""output""}]";
        var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MinhaClasse>>(json);
    }
```

Para este exemplo foi utilizado a biblioteca NewtonSoft que pode ser obtida através do NuGet.